# Possible to access clipboard (copy/paste) in Silverlight (even 4 OOB?)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, clipboard, silverlight-oob

Is it possible in Silverlight (I can use SL4 OOB if required) to copy/paste into my application? It appears I can only copy/paste text (from what I read)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with Silverlight 4 but only for Unicode text (Remarks in [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)). If it is enough you can read [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2009/11/21/silverlight-4-clipboard-access.aspx).

If you want different content you could try using COM object (requiers OOB, [tutorial](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-videos/com-object-access-trusted-applications/)) as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ClipboardActiveX.aspx) (its not for Silverlight and it's ActiveX but idea is the same).

Comment: Is it only for text? What about images? eg. from PrintScr

Comment: No, Silverlight only has access to plain unicode text in the clipboard.

Comment: @Henrik Söderlund, if its for activex, then it will work only in IE right?

Comment: if you are using OOB it doesn't matter because your app will be working outside of browser but not on Mac OsX.

Comment: Exactly. OOB + COM Automation is required, and that means Windows only.